# How to insert multi function into array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How to push multi function into array stack[]. I using for loop or while loop to push it but it show message error. maybe it must use async. help me. tks. This is a part of my script. a array is multi link stored before.

```
var obArr = []
var stack = []
var j,
    count = 0

 while (count < a.length) {
stack.push(function(callback) {
    request(a[count], function(error, response, body) {

        let dom = body
        if (!error) {
            $ = cheerio.load(dom)

        } else {
            console.log('nothing')
        }
        $('.phone_number').each(function() {
            sdt = $(this).text()
        })
        $('.member').each(function() {
            email = $(this).text()
            vl = validateEmail(email)
            if (vl) {
                email = $(this).text()
                email = email.replace(/\s/g, '')
            } else {
                email = ' '
            }
        })
        callback(null, sdt, email)
    })

})
count++
}

// stack.push(getData)
async.parallel(stack, function(err, result) {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(result)
})

}
```

)

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: D:\Node\node_modules\request\index.js:45
    throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.')
    ^
This is my error. Maybe uri at a[count] not work, If i  don't use while loop and change by a[0] it work. 
Error: undefined is not a valid uri or options object.
    at request (D:\Node\node_modules\request\index.js:45:11)
    at D:\Node\baitap\parralle\2.js:34:13
    at D:\Node\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3830:24
    at eachOfArrayLike

Comment: What you posted has one to many }) at the end

Comment: What is `a`? That is the issue, it has nothing to do with pushing function into `stack`

Comment: a[] is array have 40 child. i was hided it.

Comment: where is request defined?

Comment: this is more suited to a for loop instead of a while loop

Comment: For loop not work. If delete while loop and change a[count] = a[0] everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your while loop like below.

```
while (count < a.length) {
  stack.push((function(url) {
    return function(callback) {
      request(url, function(error, response, body) {
          ... original code here ...
      });
    };
  })(a[count]));
  count++;
}
```

Be careful of `url` paremeter and `a[count]`.
When functions in `a[]` are called by `async,parallel`, the value of `count` is already `a.length`, so `a[a.length]` is `undefined`.

You need to bind url in a[count] when creating your function because it will be called asynchronously by `async.parallel`. You can find more info about this kind of pattern [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Comment: god. This seem ok. but i have a issue with result. the result just show 17/40 have data and 23/40 show undefined. maybe request() can't load some url and can't get dom html in this some page. but tks for your help